# UIActivityIndicatorView not animating after appearing within transitionWithView

Tags: ios, uiview, ios5, uiactivityindicatorview

There is a subview of my main view, with a UIActivityIndicatorView in it. Initially the `hidden` property of this subview is set to `YES`.

I want this subview to fade onto the screen. I have used the following code to achieve this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:3.0
                   options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                animations:^{
                    self.subviewWithActivitySpinnerInIt.hidden = NO;
                }
```

Even though the activity indicator is set to animating, it doesn't animate after appearing with the above code. However if I replace the code above with the line below - in the exact same spot - then when the activity indicator appears it is animating.

```
self.subviewWithActivitySpinnerInIt.hidden = NO;
```

Any idea what's going on?

*(Using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried also adding the code to the completion block?  The completion parameter is missing in the question.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:3.0
                   options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                animations:^{ self.subviewWithActivitySpinnerInIt.hidden = NO; }
                completion:^{ self.subviewWithActivitySpinnerInIt.hidden = NO; }];
```

As an alternative, though it may not be suited to your needs, you might want to consider using animateWithDuration instead of transitionWithView.  I think the code below is equivalent:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                      delay:nil
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     self.subviewWithActivitySpinnerInIt.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil ];
```